# Vertex AI executor with .env file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Normally when using environment variables in Docker you would specify them with ENV command in the Dockerfile or give the .env file with the --env-file option in a docker run command.

When creating a Vertex AI notebook executor this latter option is not available while the first option requires maintenance of the Dockerfile when an env variable changes.
We can specify the env variables as parameters in a .yaml when creating the executor, but that requires again an extra step editing in the process when a env variable changes.

How can we pass the content of the .env file to the container at runtime with no extra effort in Vertex AI?

Comment: The environment variables can be passed to a [custom container](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-container). You can refer to this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex_custom_training_prediction#3).

Comment: Custom container does the job

Comment: I would call it a workaround as one needs to put the env in the container, while docker allows to set env variables at runtime. This allows using same container with different environments, e.g. by sharing the container between multiple people, each specifying their own environment variables with private tokens/api keys